# Closed-form solution for an integral involving the p.d.f. and c.d.f. of a $N(0, 1)$-distributed random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, integral

Let $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ be the probability and cumulative density functions, respectively, of a random variable with distribution $\text{N}(0,\,1)$. I was wondering if you could help me to compute
$$\int_{-\infty}^{w}\phi(x)\cdot\Phi(a+b\cdot x)\,\text{d}x\mbox{,}$$
where $(a,\,b,\,w)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $b\neq 0$, please. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I find this one and delete my answer, when i read comments, I cannot help laughing, math.stackexchange.com/questions/381308/… The idea is to express $e^{−x^2/2}$as Maclaurin series, I think –

Comment: Hi, @DeepNorth. I am looking for a closed-form expression for the integral in the question because integrals decrease the efficiency of an algorithm I am programming in R-software. After examining the answer provided in the link, I do not know whether it will contribute to improve the efficiency of my algorithm. I will have a try. Thanks.

Comment: An appropriately chosen series may converge extremely rapidly.  Alternatively, consider a saddlepoint approximation: this kind of integral is particularly amenable to that approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @whuber. I will spend some time learning about saddlepoint approximations before approximating the integral in the question.

Comment: Hi, nice people. This question was answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283928/closed-form-solution-for-an-integral-involving-the-p-d-f-and-c-d-f-of-a-n0-1).